# Image not displayed in Outlook in ASP

Tags: c#, email, outlook, umbraco7

After sending an email the logo is not displayed in Outlook but it works in Gmail.

I found that in the inspect element that the image src is changed into `blockedimagesrc`

In my Controller :

```
var NotifyCompany = new NotifyCompany()
{
   Email = model.regE,
   EmailTo = contact.GetPropertyValue<string>("email"),
   DateRegistered = DateTime.UtcNow
};
EmailHelpers.SendEmail(NotifyCompany, "NotifyCompany", "New Client Registered");
```

Helpers :

```
public static ActionResponse SendEmail(IEmail model, string emailTemplate, string subject, List<HttpPostedFileBase> files = null)
{
    try
    {
        var template =
        System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Templates/{0}.cshtml", emailTemplate)));
        var body = Razor.Parse(template, model);

        var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        if (files != null && files.Any())
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var att = new Attachment(file.InputStream, file.FileName);
                attachments.Add(att);
            }
        }

        var email = Email
        .From(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email:From"], "myWebsiteEmail")
        .To(model.EmailTo)
        .Subject(subject)
        .Attach(attachments)
        .Body(body).BodyAsHtml();

        email.Send();
        return new ActionResponse()
        {
            Success = true
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new ActionResponse()
        {
            Success = false,
            ErrorMessage = ex.Message
        };
    }
}
```

In my Email Template :

```
<img src="/mysite.com/image/logo.png"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you use `<img src="http://yoursitenameheresincestackoverflowwontletmeuseyourexactsitename.com/image/logo.png"/>` instead?

Comment: The image will not display.

Comment: @mjwills Both Http & Http is not working in display logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook web access will block any images by default - only if the user chooses to display/download images these will be displayed/downloaded. I am not sure if it is possible to adjust the default behavior by using office 365 admincenter or the OWA settings.

Some time ago it was possible to work around this by using it as a background image inside a table>tr>td cell `background-image` css property.

***EDIT***

Checked a recent project of myself, where we are sending notification mails about tickets. The site logo is displayed correctly in outlook/owa - without adding the recipient to the trusted list:

```
            using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(sender, header.RecipientAddress, header.Subject, header.Body))
            {
                mm.Body = header.Body;
                mm.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
                mm.Priority = priority == IntMailPriority.High ? MailPriority.High : MailPriority.Normal;
                mm.IsBodyHtml = bodyIsHtml;

                // logo
                if (bodyIsHtml)
                {
                    AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(header.Body, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");

                    string logoPath = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\\images\\logo_XXX.png";
                    LinkedResource siteLogo = new LinkedResource(logoPath)
                        {
                            ContentId = "logoId"
                        };
                    htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(siteLogo);
                    mm.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
                }

                // create smtpclient
                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpSettings.ServerAddress, smtpSettings.Port)
                                    {
                                        Timeout = 30000,
                                        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
                                    };
                // set relevant smtpclient settings 
                if (smtpSettings.UseTlsSsl)
                {
                    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

                    // needed for invalid certificates
                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
                }
                if (smtpSettings.UseAuth)
                {
                    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

                    NetworkCredential smtpAuth = new NetworkCredential { UserName = smtpSettings.Username, Password = smtpSettings.Password };
                    smtpClient.Credentials = smtpAuth;
                }

                smtpClient.Timeout = smtpSettings.SendingTimeout * 1000;

                // finally sent mail \o/ :)
                try
                {
                    smtpClient.Send(mm);
                }
                catch (SmtpException exc)
                {
                    throw new ProgramException(exc, exc.Message);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException exc)
                {
                    throw new ProgramException(exc, exc.Message);
                }
                catch (AuthenticationException exc)
                {
                    throw new ProgramException(exc, exc.Message);
                }
            }
```

Afterwards the logo is referred to as

```
<IMG alt="Intex Logo" src="cid:logoId">
```

inside the generated html.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new in this outlook email at least I know now. thanks for the great information.


P.S. `background-image` is not working.

Comment: Hi @dsdel, Follow up question, when client's use a MS Outlook App the styles is not working. (margin, padding, etc..) also the site logo is not displayed but the social icons are displayed.

Any Idea about this?

Comment: @Marky please check my updated post - perhaps your mail is not sent correctly as html? The function in the post is working correctly.

Comment: @dsdel, The inline css is not working in Desktop Outlook App.. my Social Icons they don't have a space (margin-right). So I think the css is not working?

Comment: @Marky but can you see the icons now?